# How to save a recorded video to a specified file in phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, save

Hi Im am trying to create a phonegap app where you save a recorded video to a folder instead of the gallery any ideas how? ive looked at the File_URI and just cant figure out how?! ive thought of just doing it in the capture.js file(creating new functions and putting in precautions so the same file is not created everytime theres a picture taken) but, will it not save them to both the gallery and my specified folder then????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way with an image:

First get setup the taking picture options with a destinationtype of a FILE_URI

var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

```
            navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onPhotoDataSuccess, this.onFailTakingPicture,
                {
                    quality: 80,
                    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 250,
                    targetHeight: 250,
                });
```

When the picture is taken the onPhotoDataSucces is called with the imageURI. Then request the filesystem of phonegap.

```
onPhotoDataSuccess : function(imageURI) {

                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, this.gotFileSystem, this.failFileSystem);

            },
```

When you got the fileSystemEntry then create a directory in the root of SD

```
 gotFileSystem: function(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory("voetstappen_opdrachten", {create: true, exclusive: false}, this.gotDirEntry, this.failFileSystem)
        },
```

In the callback function `this.gotDirEntry()` you got the directory object(dirEntry) which you can use to set to an object's property so you can use it later to save the file to

```
  gotDirEntry: function (dirEntry) {
                    //set a object's propery with the dirEntry
                    this.dirEntry = dirEntry
                    // use the resolveLocalFileSystemUri to save the captured image to a file
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(this.imageURI, this.gotFileEntry, this.failFileSystem);
                },
```

And finally you got the fileEntry and then move it to the direntry like this:

```
           gotFileEntry: function(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.moveTo(this.dirEntry, "objective" + "name" + ".jpg", function(fileEntry){ //callback } 
}
```

Comment: well thanks for your input you put me on the right track.
i decided to go at it this way.

Comment: First a function to check for a file

function checkIfFileExists(fileExists)     
{    
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,   function(fileSystem)    
    {    
        fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false },   fileExists);    
    });    
}    
function fileExists(fileEntry){    
    return true;    
}

Comment: sorry about my abysmal effort to write code in here... I will gracefully give up 
thanks @Sjaak